# Grouping in SQL Server 2008 R2 by min value of the group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I am running this command in sql

```
select ID, TASK, CreatedBy,CreateDate
from John Results group by ID, TASK, CreatedBy, CreateDate
```

which is returning this

```
20  text    user1   2008-11-07 19:10:47.230
20  text    user2   2008-11-07 17:45:17.993
24  text    user3   2008-11-07 18:58:08.727
25  text    user4   2008-11-07 20:19:01.293
36  text    user5   2008-11-10 21:31:23.610
37  text    user6   2008-11-10 21:34:09.597
38  text    user7   2008-11-10 21:35:19.660
```

There are two ID's that are 20 and I am trying to get the result with the lowest date so in this example it would be

```
20  text    user2   2008-11-07 17:45:17.993
```

How would I go about doing that for all the duplicate ID's
Thank you very much

Comment: You have CreatedBy in your select and are grouping by CreatedBy as well so since id 20 has user1 and user2 you are still going to get both rows

Comment: when I don't include it in the grouping I get an error    invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: correct if it is in your select list it also needs to be in your group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    WITH mycte
    (id, createdate, createdby, rownum)
    AS
    (
     SELECT id, createdate,createdby,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY createdate  ASC) AS ROWNUM
     FROM johnresults
    )

    SELECT j.id, j.task, mycte.createdby, mycte.createdate 
    FROM
    johnresults j
    inner join mycte ON j.id = mycte.id and mycte.rownum = 1
    GROUP BY j.id, j.task, mycte.createdby, mycte.createdate
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select ID, TASK, FIRST(CreatedBy),MIN(CreateDate) as 'LowestDate'
from John Results group by ID, TASK, CreatedBy, CreateDate 
having CreateDate = LowestDate
```

Comment: that still has two id's of 20 when I run it

Comment: Duplicate of first answer. Question: do you only want results for rows that have duplicates?

Comment: no, I want all the rows but with the ones that have duplicates just display the one with the lowest date

Comment: select ID, TASK, CreatedBy, min(CreateDate) as 'LowestDate'
from John Results group by ID, TASK, CreatedBy having CreateDate = LowestDate'

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, TASK, CreatedBy, min(CreateDate) as 'LowestDate'
from John Results 
group by ID, TASK, CreatedBy
```

Comment: that still returns the same set

Comment: Sorry, check the edit, you should remove the "CreateDate" from your group by.

Comment: and again. still the same set.. I think its becuase there are two different people in the createdby.

Comment: Yes, having user1 and user2 will cause that.  The best option in that case might be to include a WHERE clause.